# syncing all objects of two git repositories

Tags: git

On our server we have a production git repository with some proprietary workflow around it which happens to hold important commits only in some reflog. For backup purposes we want to sync the whole repository to a second repository.

One way would be a simple `git push --all`. Unfortunately this will only push objects referred by some known ref, ignoring those referred only by some reflog. Is there some way to tell `git push` to push the reflogs (and the corresponding commits!), too? (I currently can only think of manually creating a fake octopus merge with all entries of the reflog.)

Another way would be some backup on file system level like `rsync`. This would probably work but the repositories are quite big and git might repackage its commits. Therefore this might take a long time.

Is there some way of listing all objects in both repositories, comparing them, and only transmit the missing objects? Is there already some built-in feature for this kind of task? What would be the best way to do it manually, otherwise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370929/how-do-i-keep-two-git-repositories-in-sync

Comment: No, that one is completely unrelated.

Comment: The entire repo is contained in the `.git` folder. If you copy that to somewhere else, you'll have effectively backed up everything, including the reflog, which are just some text files in `.git/logs`.

Comment: That is exactly what I did with the `rsync` above. With a huge repository this will need to transfer lots of data, which is already present on the other side, but packed in a different way. - The aim is to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly important to preserve these specific commits in the reflag, it's probably worth giving them some label (either a tag, or a branch name reflecting the "proprietary workflow"). Without knowing more, it seems risky to want to keep those commits, but not have anything except reflags refer to them, meaning they could be garbage collected at some future time unexpectedly.

But, without questioning your process any further  ;)  I don't believe there's a command that gives you exactly what you're looking for (a complete list of objects in the two repositories). The closest I can think of is git reflag itself, which accepts all the log options to filter and format the objects in the reflag. If you can formulate an appropriate query for log, perhaps you could have it output just the commit objects you find "important" but aren't listed in any other ref, and feed those results into git-pack-objects. (Your idea of an octopus merge is a promising one as a way to identify them)

Comment: Well it's not "my process". It's some "enterprise software" doing so. The reflogs are explicitly configured to never expire. Giving each reflog entry an explicit tag would result in a lot of tags. This is why my only idea was to merge them in order to be able to cover them by a single ref.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing for pushing (or pulling) reflogs, but it would be easy to "fake it" by using the hierarchical nature of the `refs/` space to make up temporary (or maybe even not that temporary) refs and pushing those.  You could then run a post-push script—perhaps even do this directly from post-receive—to build the desired reflogs on the other end, using `git update-ref`.

Let's say (for design sketch purposes) you choose `refs/sync/` as the top level of your new name-space.  Then:

```
# find reflogs - change this to use the ones you care about
unfiltered=$(
    for refname in $(cd $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/logs &&
            find * -type f -print); do
        echo $refname
    done
)

filtered=... # something ...

filtered="HEAD refs/heads/master" # for now

for reflog in $filtered; do
    # change name from (.*)@{([0-9]+)} to \1/\2
    # (keep commit ID at left)
    git reflog --no-abbrev $reflog |
        sed -n 's,\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)@{\([0-9][0-9]*\)}:.*,\1 \2/\3,p'
done
```

The output from this (so far) is a sequence of hash values and names, so it can then be piped to:

```
while read hash name; do
    git update-ref -m 'create for transport' refs/sync/$name $hash
done
```

Now you can `git push` the `refs/sync/` namespace to the remote, then delete all the `refs/sync/` names (either delete the ones created here, or just delete all `refs/sync/` names up front—you might want to do that anyway in case one of these update sequences is interrupted):

```
git for-each-ref --format 'git update-ref -d %(refname)' refs/sync/ | sh
```

On the remote, having received `refs/sync/*` refs, you can then turn them back into reflog entries by reversing the above process (it's even a bit easier, you just want to reverse-sort numerically by final component so that the oldest log entries are update-ref'ed first).

As the other answer says, depending this heavily on reflogs might not be all that wise.  You could use the above techniques to turn existing reflog entries into something more permanent (like tags, which already live in `refs/tags/`; you could perhaps use a subset name-space, `refs/tags/autotag/NNN` for instance).